# Apply a tensorflow operator separately onto each data in a batch, but needs to run them in parallel

Tags: python, tensorflow

We know that Tensorflow built-in operators support parallel processing in GPU, so we only need to feed data of shape `N x H x W x C` to the operators, that it will give us a result of shape `N x ...`.

However, now I have an operator which can be implemented to support only one image data, i.e., we can only feed data of shape `H x W x C` to it. To make it support batch processing, a straight-forward solution is, slice each data from the batch, and separately feed it into one operator, then merge the output together. The code may look like:

```
# input is of shape N x H x W x C
ys = []
for i in range(N):
    x = tf.slice(input, [i, 0, 0, 0], [1, -1, -1, -1])
    y = MyOwnOperator(x)
    ys += y
output = tf.concat(ys, axis=0)
```

As you may see it, the for loop as above is not in parallel. So is there a solution to make the for loop be processed in parallel too?

Comment: Look into inception networks using Tensorflow, they also achieve a similar goal

Comment: I think you need [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn). Note operating element-wise is usually significantly slower in TensorFlow, so the ideal solution, if possible, would be to vectorize your operation so it can operate directly on the whole batch.